# Timer does not start with opening a file with openFiledialog

Tags: c#, timer, openfiledialog

I want to open excel file using openfiledialog() and show it in datagridview 
I want to start timer when i press open in openfiledialog
But timer start when file completely loaded in datagridview;

Comment: Sample Code..??

Comment: start the time after ShowDialog() ?

Comment: You could also add a FileOK event - which fires when you click on the open button - & start the timer from there.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:

@PaulF is right, **no need** for `WndProc` try **this**,

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
         timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

You can capture `OpenFileDialog` window by `WndProc`, here is an example,

```
bool IsOpenFileDialog = false; // global variable to check if openfile opened

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     IsOpenFileDialog = true; // button opens openfile dialog on click event
     openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // show it, it waits until dialog closed
     IsOpenFileDialog = false; // after closed set it to false
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     textBox1.Text += "Ticking! \n"; // added a textbox to show the ticking 
}


protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
      base.WndProc(ref m);
      if (m.Msg == 289) // check message loop
      {
         if (!timer1.Enabled && IsOpenFileDialog) {
      // if timer is not running already and button clicked to open openfiledialog
            timer1.Start(); // start timer
         }
      }
}
```

[image]
Hope helps,

Comment: I maybe wrong but I think OP wants to start the timer when the OpenFileDialog Open button is clicked - not when the dialog is displayed.

Comment: Yes bro, misunderstood, you are right. Corrected. @PaulF

Comment: Thanks, But I want timer start when Open Button clicked after selecting file name. (At Closing OpenFileDialog).

Comment: Okay, before the gray line (the edit part), it works as you desired. @saleemkalro